# TD borders not rendered correctly with Firefox

Tags: html, css, windows, firefox, dpi

Better check if it's a code issue before reporting a bug to Firefox dev team... Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdt7ktqa/1/) of a little `table` css-styled. The CSS is quite very simple :

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 1em;
}

th {
  background-color: #a0a0d8;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20em;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #8080b8;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Sadly, and **without any zoom**, I got irregular borders as displayed [image].

Did I make some mistake, or is it an issue which should be reported (didn't find such report exepcte ones about a zoom) ?

Note : zooming forward or backward gets borders regular for some coefficient.

**Edit** : here is the HTML as requested :

```
<div class="content">
  <table id="groups">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="groupes">Groupes</th>
        <th class="action add" title="Ajouter un nouveau groupe">+</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="new-group-tr" style="display: none;">
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="new-group-name">
        </td>
        <td class="action add" title="Valider la création du groupe">V</td>
        <td class="action cancel" title="Annuler">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Aucun »">
        <td class="groupes">Aucun</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Aucun »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Groupe_1 »">
        <td class="groupes">Group2</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Groupe_1 »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « New »">
        <td class="groupes">Group3</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « New »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Test »">
        <td class="groupes">Group4</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Test »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Test 2 »">
        <td class="groupes">Group4</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Test 2 »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Test 3 »">
        <td class="groupes">Group5</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Test 3 »">X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr title="Cliquer pour afficher le contenu du groupe « Test 4 »">
        <td class="groupes">Group6</td>
        <td class="action delete" title="Supprimer le groupe « Test 4 »">X</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Edit 2 :** tested with FireFox 44, Windows Seven Pro.

**Edit 3 :** screen is 120DPI (125%).

**Edit 4 :** 120DPI according to windows, 166 according to [DPILove](http://dpi.lv/)...

Comment: We need a *complete* code example in your question. HTML too please.

Comment: You can see it in the fiddle... Pasting it here is relevant ?

Comment: Probably an HTML problem, a <td> instead of </td>... we need HTML code for that

Comment: I can see the problem in the fiddle, but only if zooming in, sorry.

Comment: Please post a complete example *here*. If a third part site like jsFiddle is ever inaccessible, or simply goes away, then your question becomes incomplete and immediately loses all value to future visitors.

Comment: **Without any zoom** here is your code working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/frpgzyy6/)

Comment: Sounds like it's related to the dpi... Though Chrome and IE don't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Mine is 150PPI and is working Fine. check yours [here](http://dpi.lv/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle looks fine in my Firefox. My screen DPI is 96.

Comment: @dippas 166 DPI according to [DPI Love](http://dpi.lv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Firefox doesn't render `border-collapse:collapse` nicely.

As a workaround, you could try using `border-collapse:separate` + `border-spacing:0`, and draw the borders separately.

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #8080b8;
}
th {
  border-top: 1px solid #8080b8;
}
th,
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #8080b8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8080b8;
}
th.action,
td.action {
  border: 0;
}
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdt7ktqa/3/)**

Comment: I have tested that updated fiddle demo, the thickness of the borders are even at any level of zooming, on latest Firefox Mac here.